# Unable To install Ubuntu on MSI Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios, acpi

I have recently bought an **MSI PE62 7RD** laptop. The problem is that I'm not able to install Ubuntu on my laptop. The installation is freezing during the booting into USB. The culprit for this kind of behavior seems to originate from a BIOS [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193531).

I have completely updated my BIOS and still I cannot install Ubuntu.

I am currently running Windows 10 in legacy-mode and I plan to dual-boot my system.

This occurs during initial boot from USB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcGiZ.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution for the problem. First During the initial boot time
press e in the grub or tab during installation and add `acpi=off` after `quiet splash` This turns off the acpi functionality. after entering the os install updates in ubuntu with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

after installing update turn off computer using manual power-off button since acpi shutdown  wont work. Now you can use your ubuntu without any problem