# Boot from usb stick hangs on MSI laptop

Tags: boot, usb, laptop, msi

I created a USB live stick from 20.04 LTS and tried to use it on an MSI laptop. It hung partway through booting with no obvious error message.

The solution here worked:
[Unable To install Ubuntu on MSI Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963086/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-laptop)

Another site recommended adding nomodeset, which I haven't tried (found it after the first answer). It enables ubuntu to boot without proprietary display drivers.

What would have to change to prevent the need for these manual interventions? Is there a way to build in the appropriate fallback response, even if it relies only on a lack of boot progress detected via a timeout?

It would be useful because the acpi=off solution didn't come up in my initial searches, probably since I was just trying to *boot* from a usb stick and not to *install*. (Hopefully this question will help solve that search gap :)

And does it make sense that either of these fixes in isolation should result in successful boot on MSI laptops? Is there some common problem that can be fixed by either acpi=off or nomodeset? Later I tried nomodeset, and I can confirm that it also allows ubuntu to boot. However, acpi=off provided better results. My system was able to boot at native resolution (1080p). Perhaps nomodeset also implies acpi=off?

Comment: It is a problem for Linux that some manufacturers of graphics chips/cards (and also some other kinds of hardware) are unwilling to provide free drivers (for their hardware). So Ubuntu and other Linux distros cannot distribute such drivers, but end users are allowed to download them, 'proprietary drivers'. Particularly for new and advanced hardware it has not been possible to work around this problem so that it will be convenient for the end users.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what is the problem.
But I had problem with installing Ubuntu 20.04 and the latest version of Win10 both together on GP73 Leopard 8RE.
So I first backed up both my HDD and SSD with free version of Macrium Reflect.
then I made the UEFI/BIOS settings to default and set it to only UEFI and also disabled the secure boot. then installed the Win10 on 1TB HDD and then installing Ubuntu 20.04 on 128SSD, But after rebooting the grub got ruined since first the windows10 booted up. but it is ok because both they are separate and they work fine by pressing F11 at boot time so I can choose which one HDD(Win10) or SSD(Ubuntu 20.04). I used rufus and made both win10 and ubuntu usb installation usbs UEFI.
I hope it will help you.