# Ubuntu 23.10 stuck on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 23.10

After an update that happened to my Ubuntu, when i boot i'm always stuck to the loading menu with the MSI logo and Ubuntu.
What can i do to resolve that issue and access my ubuntu ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? - [Unable To install Ubuntu on MSI Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963086/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-laptop)

Comment: One user with MSI posted this: found where MSI locked the boot order in the BIOS.
In the MSI UEFI BIOS Setting, Toggle from Advanced Mode to Basic Mode. Bottom of list